# xamppp lampp unistall and error

Tags: mysql, php, lamp

Today I installed **xampp** from their website and just downloaded and extracted on my linux os (using `tar xvfz`) command and I started it using `/lampp start`.
everything started perfectly and I wanted it to be secure so I ran the command `/opt/lampp/lampp security` and gave some passwords.
I ran **localhost** on my browser and then clicked on **phpmyadmin** but it asked a **username** and a **password** I couldnt log in so I removed the whole xampp with `rm-rf/opt` lampp command and again installed as above but now when i start i get a messgae like dis:
another daemon is already running for all php mysql ftp and all other services how to correct this if u can let me know how to remove everything nd reinstall it again. or how to fix problem I have uninstalled and reinstalled about 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the XAMPP directory again and rebooting. You can reinstall if you want, but I personally think that [installing a LAMP stack as the Community Documentation describes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP) would be a much better idea. You'll also want to `apt-get install phpmyadmin`.

Edit: Or you could just `sudo apt-get install php5 mysql-server apache2 phpmyadmin`. I think that would actually be my preferred method personally.

Edit2: Your phpMyAdmin will be accessible at `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`, and your files will go in `/var/www`.